# MongoDB getList("field-name", Double::class.java); produces ClassCastException in Kotlin

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin

I'm trying to retrieve a field containing an array of `Double` from MongoDB, but I'm receiving a

> ```
> ClassCastException: List element cannot be cast to double.
> ```

The class is written in Kotlin, and the part of the code that produces the exception is:

```
val coordinates = doc.getList(FIELD_COORDINATES, Double::class.java)
```

This works:

```
val coordinates = doc.get(FIELD_COORDINATES) as List<Double>
```

And the equivalent code in Java works too:

```
final List<Double> coordinates = doc.getList(FIELD_COORDINATES, Double.class);
```

[image]

Please let me know if this is a bug in Kotlin or there's a mistake in my code.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of `Double::class.java` in Java is `double.class`, not `Double.class`. That would be written as `java.lang.Double::class.java` in Kotlin, or [`Double::class.javaObjectType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-object-type.html).

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Alexey is correct. Here is an example how it should look like:

```kotlin
val coordinates = doc.getList("coordinates", Double::class.javaObjectType)
```

Notice the use of the Java ObjectType of Double.